# Is it actually possible to instantiate SPField?

Tags: spfield, addfieldasxml

I want to create a custom List programmatically from scratch:

1. First I add:

   ```
   Guid listID = web.Lists.Add(title, description, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
   list = web.Lists[listID];
   ```
2. Then I want to create custom Fields specific to that List.

   I look at the constructors for SPField, and what do I see?

   ```
   public SPField(
       SPFieldCollection fields,
       string fieldName
   )
   ```

   It's already awkward to know that I need to specify which SPFieldCollection will my SPField be in. Nevertheless I try the obvious way:

   ```
   SPFieldCollection fieldCollection = list.Fields;
   SPField newField = new SPField(fieldCollection, "Name");
   ```

And guess what happens then? An error occurs: `Field with name "Name" was not found.`

So basically if I want to create a Field, I need to have SPFieldCollection which will have such Field already within?!

So I'm asking: Is it actually possible to create (instantiate) SPField? *(Apart from the AddFieldAsXml method)*

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to create a field without using AddFieldAsXml.

```
SPList lst = oSPWeb.Lists["EmpList"];
 /* create a Text field for Name */
 SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                        SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "Name");
 fldName.Required = true;
 fldName.MaxLength = 50;
/* add the new fields to the list */
 lst.Fields.Add(fldName);
```

[Add Columns / Fields Programmatically to a SharePoint List](http://burnignorance.com/sharepoint-tips-and-hacks/add-columns-fields-programmatically-to-a-sharepoint-list/)